# Simple Nuxt 3 Page Transition not working

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I'm discovering Nuxt 3 and and simply want to make an animation between pages. The idea is to use javascript hooks to make page transitions using js library such as gsap or animeJs.

So in my `app.vue` file, I simply put `<NuxtPage/>` into `<Transition>` element like this :

```
<NuxtLayout>
    <Transition>
        <NuxtPage/>
    </Transition>
</NuxtLayout>
```

My vue pages ('./pages/index.vue' and './pages/project/myproject.vue') look like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>My Project</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
function onEnter(el, done) {
    done()
}
function onLeave(el, done) {
    done()
}
</script>
```

I have followed both Nuxt 3 and Vue 3 documentations :

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages#layouttransition-and-pagetransition

https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#javascript-hooks

I also read this thread on github, but I can't find answer :
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/851

When i was using **Nuxt 2** I only need to put transition object into my  page like this and it's working fine :

```
<script>
export default {
    // ... (datas, methods)
    transition: {
        mode: "in-out",
        css: false,
        enter(el, done) {
            console.log("enter");
            done()
        },
        leave(el, done) {
            console.log("leave");
            done()
        }
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-center text-5xl">Hello World</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nuxt 3 doesn't need a `<Transition>` wrapper around pages/layouts, by default it does that for you.
Take a look at [this starter template](https://github.com/viandwi24/nuxt3-awesome-starter): in `assets/sass/app.scss`, the last part of the style is page and layout transition.
You can tweak the default named animations (`page-` and `layout-`).
More infos [here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/851)

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked as the answer. It does not answer the question about transitions with js hooks?

Comment: This does not answer how to create transitions using hooks.

Answer (score 4):

Just follow [the official documentation for Nuxt 3](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/transitions#page-transitions). You need to add the following code to your `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' }
  },
})
```

And then apply the classes inside your `app.vue` file, like this:

```js
<template>
  <NuxtPage />
</template>

<style>
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.page-enter-from,
.page-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(1rem);
}
</style>
```

Nuxt 3 uses the Vue's `<Transition>` component under the hood, so you don't need to add it in the template.

Be careful with **the css prefix**.

Comment: it doesn not work for me

Answer (score 1):

If the transitions don't work for you, remember that the `<style>` tag in **App.vue** cannot have a `scoped` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

nuxt 3 does not support `transition` tag in for layouts/pages.
According to the [Nuxt.js](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/transitions#transitions) document, for page transitions, you must first add the below code to nuxt.config.ts to apply an automatic transition for all pages:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   app: {
       pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' }
   },
})
```

then, To start adding transitions between your pages, add the following CSS to your app.vue:

`style` is not **scoped**.

```
<template>
  <NuxtPage />
</template>

<style>
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.page-enter-from,
.page-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(1rem);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

How to use components?

```html
<!--components/im/index.vue-->
<template>
    <ClientOnly>
        <Transition name="fade">
            <div>test</div>
        </Transition>
    </ClientOnly>
</template>
<script setup>

</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please add supporting details, links or an explanation to improve your answer. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).